# How to fix chat connection issues

Tags: technical-issues, warframe

Chat constantly closes connection to the remote host.
It has become a problem, if someone messages me I can't see it. Sometimes, it reconnects automatically, sometimes I have to open chat to force it to reconnect.
[image: chat being closed by the remote host]
This happened after I've came back from a mission.
The Error code refers to a [Windows Sockets Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx) which describes: [image: WSAECONNRESET Code]

> Connection reset by peer.
>
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. This normally results if the peer application on the remote host is suddenly stopped, the host is rebooted, the host or remote network interface is disabled, or the remote host uses a hard close (see setsockopt for more information on the SO_LINGER option on the remote socket). This error may also result if a connection was broken due to keep-alive activity detecting a failure while one or more operations are in progress. Operations that were in progress fail with WSAENETRESET. Subsequent operations fail with WSAECONNRESET.

**What I tried so far:**
Port forward ports 4950 ~ 4955
Make a new rule to allow all connections through ports 4950 ~ 4955

In in-game settings, change to new port, port 4960 ~ 4965
Port forward ports 4960 ~ 4965
Make a new rule to allow all connections through ports 4960 ~ 4965
In both cases, I have made sure all traffic going through these ports weren't restricted.

Google to search for a solution.
None of them offered a long-term solution

Comment: Lol, I have the same error in an C# application I am working on. Joke aside, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have port forwarded, and then added a new rule to those ports in my firewall to make sure nothing was conflicting

Comment: This sounds like you do have restrictions on your firewall. If that is the case, what happens if you remove all restrictions?